# Intensity of hive query execution estimate before execution

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql, cloudera-cdh

I support a Hadoop cluster with HIVE service, however I am not a HIVE developer. One of the developer is running a long query (please see example below). The job fails with some cryptic error message (please see below).

I suspect that this query is too intense or not optimized or both. How can I know if the query is going to be too intense?

When I monitored the Hive server load went to just (w output) 1.5 and network bandwidth peaked at 5.7 Mbps/sec. CPU consumed by the top java processes was below 2%. I saw no real evidence that the query was breaking the hive server (only 1 hive server in the hive cluster).

Hive metastore canary duration went from <1 sec to 2.5 seconds.

How do I know is this or any other query is too intense?

Query:
    SELECT duid, GET_JSON_OBJECT(json_data, '$.app.p') as platform, MIN(GET_JSON_OBJECT(json_data, '$.generated.ats')) as first_boot_ts FROM raw.raw_events_duid WHERE app='atlas_qa' AND ds>='20160306' and ds<='20160326' AND duid ='00001656-da4f-47dc-8619-2868198ed25a' GROUP BY duid,GET_JSON_OBJECT(json_data, '$.app.p') limit 10;

Sample error on the server:
    hadoop-cmf-hive-HIVEMETASTORE-qn7bi02hdn001.compliant.disney.private.log.out:2016-05-04 12:21:58,115 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: Unable to make the expression tree from expression string [(null and (ds = '20160501'))]Error parsing partition filter; lexer error: null; exception NoViableAltException(11@[])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some null data returning when `Get_json_object` is run. Remove those two from the query and run it .. it will run fine.. there is some null data being returned from `MIN(GET_JSON_OBJECT(json_data, '$.generated.ats'))`.

Furthermore, we have `string get_json_object(string json_string, string path)`, which:

1. Extracts json object from a json string based on json path specified
2. Returns json string of the extracted json object.

   - It will return null if the input json string is invalid.

**NOTE:** The json path can only have the characters `[0-9a-z_]`, i.e., no upper-case or special characters. Also, the keys *cannot start with numbers.* This is due to restrictions on Hive column names.

hope this helps